# Generating the Shortest Regex Dynamically from a source List of Strings

Tags: c#, regex, linq, lambda, combinatorics

I have a bunch of SKUs (stock keeping units) that represent a series of strings that I'd like to create a single Regex to match for.

So, for example, if I have SKUs:

```
var skus = new[] { "BATPAG003", "BATTWLP03", "BATTWLP04", "BATTWSP04", "SPIFATB01" };
```

...I'd like to automatically generate the Regex to recognize any one of the SKUs.

I know that I could do simply do `"BATPAG003|BATTWLP03|BATTWLP04|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01"`, but list of SKUs can be quite lengthy and I'd like to compress the resulting Regex to look like `"BAT(PAG003|TW(LP0(3|4)|SP04))|SPIFATB01"`

So this is a combinatorics exercise. I want to generate the all of the possible Regex to match any of my input strings, with the view that the shortest is probably the best.

I could, for example, produce any of these:

```
BATPAG003|BATTWLP03|BATTWLP04|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01
BAT(PAG003|TW(LP0(3|4)|SP04))|SPIFATB01
BAT(PAG003|TW(LP(03|04)|SP04))|SPIFATB01
B(ATPAG003|ATTW(LP0(3|4)|ATSP04))|SPIFATB01
```

Any of those would work, but the shortest is probably the one I'd choose.

To start with I've tried to implement this function:

```
Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>> regexify = null;
regexify = xs =>
    from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    let g = xs.ToArray().Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).GroupBy(x => new String(x.Take(n).ToArray()), x => new String(x.Skip(n).ToArray()))
    let parts  = g.SelectMany(x => x.Count() > 1 ? regexify(x).Select(y => x.Key + "(" + String.Join("|", y) + ")") : new [] { x.Key + String.Join("", x) })
    let regex = String.Join("|", parts)
    orderby regex.Length
    select regex;
```

This takes my source `skus` and results in a list of possible Regex's, but it's not working. This is the current output:

```
BATPAG003|BATTWLP03|BATTWLP04|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWLP03|BATTWLP04|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|BATTWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|BATTW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|BATTW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|BATTW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|BATT(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|BATT(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|BATT(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|BATT(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TWSP04)|BAT(PAG003|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|BAT(PAG003|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|T(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|T(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|T(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TTWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TTWSP04)|BA(TPAG003|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TTW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TTW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|BA(TPAG003|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|TT(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|TT(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|TT(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)))|BA(T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|T(PAG003|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|T(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|T(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|T(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))))|SPIFATB01 
B(ATPAG003|ATTWLP03|ATTWLP04|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTWLP03|ATTWLP04|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTWLP03|ATTWLP04|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWLP0(3|4)|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(03|04)|ATTWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P03|P04)|ATTWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|ATTWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|ATTWSP04)|B(ATPAG003|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|ATTW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|ATTW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|ATTW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|B(ATPAG003|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|ATT(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|ATT(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|ATT(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|ATT(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)))|B(AT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TWSP04)|AT(PAG003|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|AT(PAG003|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|T(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|T(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|T(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))))|B(A(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TTWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TTWSP04)|A(TPAG003|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TTW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TTW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TTW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|A(TPAG003|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|TT(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|TT(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|TT(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|TT(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)))|A(T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWLP0(3|4)|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(03|04)|TWLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P03|P04)|TWL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|TWL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|TWSP04)|T(PAG003|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|TW(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|TW(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|TW(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04))|T(PAG003|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|T(WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|T(WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(03|04)|WLP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|WSP04)|T(WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P03|P04)|WL(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|WL(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|WSP04)|T(W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP03|LP04|SP04)|W(LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|LP0(3|4)|SP04)|W(LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(03|04)|LP(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4))|SP04)|W(L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P03|P04)|L(P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4)|P0(3|4))|L(P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(03|04)|P(0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)|0(3|4)))|SP04)))))|SPIFATB01
```

It feels very close, and I think I'm slightly doing something wrong.

Comment: Any reason why can't you just use `skus.Contains(sku)`?

Comment: @IanKemp: A sufficient reason is that it might be only a part of a longer regular expression. When the alternative branches start with the same characters, it causes a backtracking performance issue. Thus, the question and the approach seem quite interesting.

Comment: @IanKemp - The `skus` array is just my source list of strings to generate a single Regex that I can use to recognize any one string from the `skus` array. So in this piece of code I want to generate the Regex from the `skus`, but in my production code I'm recognizing any of the skus from the Regex. Two separate pieces of code. If it were all in one piece of code I could do `skus.Contains(sku)`, but it's not.

Comment: Why not use prefix tree?

Comment: Just a thought, perhaps you could import the sku's array if you're already somehow importing the regex to production. Interesting question

Comment: @sricks - I certainly could do that. The SKUs are basically in a flat text file, but part of the outcome for me is that I get a more compact representation of the list of SKUs that I can visually inspect. It's easier for me to visually tell if a SKU is in the list in that format rather than the flat list.

Comment: @Ante - Yes, a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be good.

Comment: @Ante - The trick would be how to implement it. I would need to create a `Func<IEnumerable<Trie<string>>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Trie<string>>>>` I think, and then flatten that out. to evaluate the best trie. It would be easy them to turn a completed `IEnumerable<Trie<string>>` into the required regex.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was thinking about using prefix tree instead a regex :-) You want to 'compress' set of strings. It seems to me that largest redundancy are string starts. There is redundancy at string ends (numbers, probably order numbers), but I suppose that number ranges depend on prefixes. With that prefix tree is probably the shortest way to describe set. Using regex that is made from prefix tree will be compiled in very similar structure as initial tree. With that, in this case, I would prefer to user a tree as representation.

Comment: @Ante - Ultimately the regex goes into a config file that I load when I run my code. It needs a string representation, so it seems natural to use regex.

Comment: @Enigmativity It is simple recursively to 'flat' trie into a string/regex. Call it FLAT(n), n is trie node. If n doesn't have children return '', if there is one child return char + FLAT(child), if there are more children return '(' + map(children, char + FLAT(child) ).join('|') + ')'

Comment: @Ante - Yep, that's the easy part. Building all of the possible tries is the hard part.

Comment: @Enigmativity Trie is uniquely defined by set of strings, and it is easy to create. Regex from trie is special case, which is probably not optimal but quite good if upper assumptions hold.

Comment: @Ante - Yes, a trie is easy to define, but it's the algorithm to run through the combinatorics of building the tries that's got me at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works if each SKU id have the same length.

```
// ...
string regexStr = Calculate(skus);
// ...

public static string Calculate(IEnumerable<string> rest) {
    if (rest.First().Length > 0) {
        string[] groups = rest.GroupBy(r => r[0])
            .Select(g => g.Key + Calculate(g.Select(e => e.Substring(1))))
            .ToArray();
        return groups.Length > 1 ? "(" + string.Join("|", groups) + ")" : groups[0];
    } else {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it work with strings of any length? I just tested with `var skus = new[] { "BATP03", "BATTWP03", "CBATTWLP04"};`, and this code generated a correct `(BAT(P03|TWP03)|CBATTWLP04)` regex. Could you please explain this code for future readers?

Comment: Try with `var skus = new[] { "BATP0", "BATP03", "BATTWP03" };`. What I do is group the skus by its first letter, and the same for the rest of the string recursively... Sorry for my English...

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Way faster than what I came up with. It did miss out on the requirement to generate every possible grouping so that I could choose the shortest version - sometime not grouping is shorter. But otherwise this is very good.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally worked out:

```
var skus = new[] { "BATPAG003", "BATTWLP03", "BATTWLP04", "BATTWSP04", "SPIFATB01" };

Func<IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>, IEnumerable<string>> regexify = null;

Func<IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>> generate =
    xs =>
        from n in Enumerable.Range(2, 20)
        let g = xs.GroupBy(x => new String(x.Take(n).ToArray()), x => new String(x.Skip(n).ToArray()))
        where g.Count() != xs.Count()
        from r in regexify(g)
        select r;

regexify = gxs =>
{
    if (!gxs.Any())
    {
        return new [] { "" };
    }
    else
    {
        var rs = regexify(gxs.Skip(1)).ToArray();
        return
            from f in gxs.Take(1)
            from z in new [] { String.Join("|", f) }.Concat(f.Count() > 1 ? generate(f) : Enumerable.Empty<string>())
            from r in rs
            select f.Key + (f.Count() == 1 ? z : $"({z})") + (r != "" ? "|" + r : "");
    }
};
```

Then using this query:

```
generate(skus).OrderBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Length);
```

...I got this result:

```
BAT(PAG003|TW(LP0(3|4)|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWLP0(3|4)|TWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTW(LP0(3|4)|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TW(LP(03|04)|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TW(LP03|LP04|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWLP(03|04)|TWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTW(LP0(3|4)|SP04)|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TT(WLP0(3|4)|WSP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTW(LP(03|04)|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTW(LP03|LP04|SP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWLP0(3|4)|TTWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWL(P0(3|4))|TWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWL(P03|P04)|TWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WLP0(3|4)|WSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTW(LP(03|04)|SP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTW(LP03|LP04|SP04)|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TT(WLP(03|04)|WSP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWLP(03|04)|TTWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BAT(PAG003|TWLP03|TWLP04|TWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WLP(03|04)|WSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TT(WL(P0(3|4))|WSP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TT(WL(P03|P04)|WSP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04))|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWL(P0(3|4))|TTWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWL(P03|P04)|TTWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WL(P0(3|4))|WSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WL(P03|P04)|WSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATT(WLP03|WLP04|WSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWLP0(3|4)|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWLP(03|04)|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BA(TPAG003|TTWLP03|TTWLP04|TTWSP04)|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWL(P0(3|4))|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01 
BATPAG003|BATTWL(P03|P04)|BATTWSP04|SPIFATB01
```

The only problem with my approach was computation time. Some of my source lists have nearly 100 SKUs. Some of the runs were taking longer than I care to wait for and had to break it down into smaller chunks and then manually concatenate.

Comment: I guess you also use `.FirstOrDefault()` at the end: `generate(skus).OrderBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Length).FirstOrDefault();`. Right? Also, this approach fails to extract the longest match (alternations in NFA regex do not have to match the longest alternative). Thus, this fails for `var skus = new[] { "BATP0", "BATP03", "BATTWP03" };` as it generates [`BAT(P0(|3)|TWP03)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=BAT(P0(%7c3)%7cTWP03)&i=BATP0%22%2c+%22BATP03%22%2c+%22BATTWP03). The other answer does not cope with this input either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Dziękuję. I appreciate you taking the time to look into this. I'll have a think. There are 5 SKUs out of about nearly 10,000 that would fall into this category.

Answer (score 0):

Take the entire list of *all* of your sku's and make a single ternary tree regex.
When you add or delete sku's, regenerate the regex. Maybe your database
generates on a weekly basis.

This utility makes a regex of 10,000 strings in less than half a second
and size is not important, it could be 300,000 strings.

For example, here is regex of [175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt).

[image]