# what can be performance-improved alternate to the following Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have list and text file and I want:

1. Find all list items that are also in string (matched words) and
   store them in list or array
2. Replace all the found matched words with "Names"
3. Count the matched words

The code is working fine, but it takes about 10 minutes to execute i want to improve the performance of the code, i have also try to use the contain function instead of the regex, but it effect on the working of the code as i am trying to matched the full words not sub-string.

Here is the code:

```
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
// Names = Millions values from the database
string Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\record-13.txt");


var letter = new Regex(@"(?<letter>\W)");

var pattern = string.Join("|", names
.Select(n => $@"((?<=(^|\W)){letter.Replace(n, "[${letter}]")}(?=($|\W)))"));

var regex = new Regex(pattern);

var matchedWords = regex
.Matches(text)
.Cast<Match>()
.Select(m => m.Value)
//.Distinct()
.ToList();

text = regex.Replace(text, "Names");

Console.WriteLine($"Matched Words: {string.Join(", ", matchedWords.Distinct())}");
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {matchedWords.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"Replaced Text: {text}");
```

Is there an alternate way to do the same thing as the above code do, with improved performance?

Comment: How large is the file.  Reading the entire file into memory and then using regex is probably using a very large amount of memory.  It is better to read the file one line at a time, replace the string and then write back to a new file.  The amount of memory used will be a lot less.  You can still use regex to modify each line of the file.

Comment: the text file is less then MB.

Comment: Two things that seem obvious: 1) your `names` seem to consist of word chars (you do not use `Regex.Escape`), so replace `((?<=(^|\W))` and `(?=($|\W))` with `\b`, 2) The problem of the regexps with alternation is that the branches may match at the same position in the string. Shrink them to only match at different positions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495000/3832970

Comment: Check task manager as code runs and see the amount of memory used.  It is possible that something else in the code is using the memory and not the regex.  So add a break point before code is run to verify amount of spare memory.

Comment: `The code is working fine, but it takes about 10 minutes to execute.` Which lines of code are taking the bulk of that time? Are you running Debug or Release builds?

Comment: The following line takes 8 minutes, and it takes about 500 MB memory:
var pattern = string.Join("|", Names
                .Select(n => $@"((?<=(^|\W)){letter.Replace(n, "[${letter}]")}(?=($|\W)))"));

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is building a regular expression with "millions" of strings embedded in it, if `Names` really contains "millions" of strings.  This is going to perform very poorly, even just to parse the regular expression, let alone evaluate it.

What you should do instead is load your Names into a `HashSet<string>`, then parse through the document one time, pulling out whole words.  You can use a regular expression or write a state machine to do this.  For each "word" you read, check if it exists in the `HashSet<string>` of names, and if so, write "Names" to your output (a `StringBuilder` would be ideal for this).  If the word is not in the Names hashset, write the actual word to your output.  Be sure to also write any non-word characters to the output as you encounter them.  When you are done, your output will contain the sanitized result, and it should complete it milliseconds rather than minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you really want; I think you can use this code instead:
If you can ignore resulting *Matched Words* and *Count*:

```
text = names.Select(name => $@"\b{name}\b")
            .Aggregate(text, (current, pattern) => Regex.Replace(current, pattern, "Names"));
```

Else:

```
var count = 0;
var matchedWord = new List<string>();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    var regex = new Regex($@"\b{name}\b");
    if (regex.IsMatch(text))
    {
        count++;
        matchedWord.Add(name);
    }

    text = regex.Replace(text, "Names");
}
```

Comment: Place it after reading text and before writing to console ;).